# Как запустить виртуальную машину на сайте?

Tags: ос, эмулятор

Существует много различных сайтов, например хостеры, предоставляющие услуги vps-серверов, которые позволяют открывать операционную систему прямо в браузере. Как такое можно реализовать? Мне нужно лишь направление, в какую сторону искать.

Comment: ` предоставляющие услуги vps-серверов, которые позволяют открывать операционную систему прямо в браузере.` - это вы имеете ввиду консоль ssh?)

Comment: нет. Не только, вернее. Windows Server к примеру. Как teamviewer онлайн по сути

Comment: Что-то у вас заголовок об одном, текст вопроса о другом. Хостеры ничего не эмулируют, они запускают самые настоящие операционные системы на самом настоящем оборудовании и предоставляют какие-нибудь способы подключиться к ним

Comment: я думал эмулятор это и есть операционная система...

Comment: И опять у вас заголовок об одном, текст вопроса о другом. Хостеры ничего не запускают на сайтах, виртуальные машины работают на серверах где-то в датацентрах и не имеют никакого отношения ни к сайтам, ни к браузерам. А если хостер предоставляет какой-то способ посмотреть на экран виртуальной машины через браузер — ну значит просто настроен какой-то механизм удалённого доступа, например VNC

Comment: Опишите вашу проблему, возможно, станет понятнее, что вам нужно. Пока что вы оперируете терминами, смысл которых сами до конца не понимаете - потому и нам вас понять сложно.

Comment: мне нужно создать сайт, который предоставит пользователям возможность управлять ос, например windows, через браузер. Например, я жму на кнопку "открыть ос", затем открывается страница, где я могу пользоваться системой. Т.е. каждый пользователь сможет пользоваться своей операционной системой, у каждого свои файлы и приложения